# shrinking a convex hull around a set of polygons

Tags: general-topology, algorithms, convex-analysis

I'm trying to find (Or design) an algorithm that will let me, after I have a convex hull, progressively shrink the hull towards the polygon set via increasing some parameter.

I.e., if we use the elastic band analogy of a convex hull, then I want to increase the pressure outside the band to progressively push the band towards the polygon set.  At infinite pressure, the band matches the polygon set.

Is there any off the shelf algorithm that does this?  Hope would I go about implementing it?